# How can I make a gradient go around a compound path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

I want a gradient to go around a compound path, like so:

[image]

<sup><sub>not necessarily a hexagon, but any compound path</sub></sup>

You can notice how the gradient is one continuous gradient that goes around the object (not straight, not radial)

---

To make this, is quite an annoying process;

- I have to have it as a stroke (doesn't work on a paths fill)
- I have to add in an extra color (whatever is the end of my gradient) to make it blend properly (also has to be aligned perfectly or it looks off)

[image]

If I need to change the "end color" there's a whole process in changing both.

---

I'm hoping there's an easier way to do this.

My concept

- A circular gradient (not radial - which is still linear)
- The idea is, just like a circle - there's **no end**, it's always blending with it's neighboring color(s):

[image]

---

### Does something like this exist?

Would this be a practical thing for Adobe to incorporate<sup>*</sup>  or is it not plausible due to limitations. (It seems pretty straightforward to my uneducated brain).

<sub>*If so, why haven't they done it yet?</sub>

Comment: Not a problem, from software perspective but it just uses up more space.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe released a new feature which can do something similar to this in their CC 2019 edition of Illustrator.

The feature is called [Freeform Gradients](https://www.adobeillustratorcc.com/whats-new/#freeformgradients) and you can read more about it [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/gradients.html#create_apply_freeform_gradient) at Adobe.

[image: image with the different gradient types]

**A** Linear Gradient         **B** Radial Gradient       **C** Freeform Gradient